# Custom attribute imported from another android project

Tags: android, attributes

From what I read [elsewhere](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9656), the compiler error "No resource identifier found" for custom attributes goes away when you change the namespace for an included project to: xmlns:si="http://schemas.android.com/apk/**lib**/com.my.base.project"  instead of "xmlns:si="http://schemas.android.com/apk/**res**/com.my.base.project"

This still doesn't solve the problem of actually reading the custom attribute's value. From a non project context. The control just gets the default value.  Any ideas to get this working?

In my application I use this custom attribute like so in a layout XML file:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:si="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.my.base.project">
       <com.my.base.project.view.CustomView
            si:collapsedHeight="100dp">
       </com.my.base.project.view.CustomView>
</merge>
```

Comment: Check the following URL too, might help understand it better:
[http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/the-case-of-android-libraries-and-custom-xml-attributes-part-2/](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/the-case-of-android-libraries-and-custom-xml-attributes-part-2/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [release notes](http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html):

> Added support for custom views with custom attributes in libraries.
>   Layouts using custom attributes must use the namespace URI
>   http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto instead of the URI that
>   includes the app package name. This URI is replaced with the app
>   specific one at build time.

They marked it as "released" with SDK Tools, Revision 17 (March 2012).

Comment: I knew the option exist but could not find the exact URI. Thanks for the pointer.