# Android: resources unavailable from library project(s) app -> liba -> libb

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, library-project

All,

I am attempting to use an existing open-source project (we'll call it A) within my app as a library. Project A also comes with its own library project (B). Project A compiles and runs just fine; however, when I try to use A within my app (I checked the 'Is Library' within A and added A to my app) I get several errors that "No resource identifier found for attribute 'X'in package..." These particular attributes exist within B. I even checked that they were added to R within A, and in fact, they were.

My question: why doesn't my app see that these resources exist?

I've searched all over and found only one situation like mine:

[Android library not pulling its resources through to other projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424199/android-library-not-pulling-its-resources-through-to-other-projects)

but I do not see that any of my resources are named the same.

I'm using Eclipse with ADT v20.0

I appreciate any help!

EDIT: If it's helpful, the open-source app I'm trying use is AnySoftKeyboard (ASK). I've also tried creating a new project and adding ASK as a library -- no dice.

EDIT2: Part of making ASK a library required converting several switch statements to if-else statements because R Ids are not declared as final for libraries.

Comment: Have you tried clean all three projects?

Comment: @yorkw Sorry, I should have mentioned that. I have tried cleaning, restarting, "un-library-ing", and "re-library-ing" multiple times. I also tried refreshing and playing with the build-path. I think I have tried other little things like that too, but that's all I can think of at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: Check out the red important changes in r17 release [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects).

Comment: @yorkw sorry, but I'm still not seeing what I need to do. The page states: "This means that library projects cannot import the R class from another library project they depend on. This is not necessary anyway, as their own R class includes all the necessary resources." Based on that, I would think it would work (and that worked for the dependency of A on B). However, I do see below: "this only happens if the references are set to be exported in the referencing project," suggesting that I need to export "references." I'm confused since I didn't need to do that from project B!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors are apparently due to the usage of custom attributes in the AnySoftKeyboard project that you converted to a library. I found that a solution is recently added into ADT (on Rev 17), mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884136/1023092).

As instructed, I tried replacing all instances of

> "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard"

with

> "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

in the newly converted library project and was able to build and run an app which includes the project (didn't really test any functionality though).

Hope this helps.

Comment: That did it. Thank you for taking the time to test that for me! I tried to vote-up your answer, but I don't have enough rep for it. This system is too strict if I can't even vote-up the answer to my own question!